# MySQL many-to-many complement set

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

I've been looking all over the net and asking people for guidance but nobody seems to know the right (relatively fast) solution to the problem:

I have three tables, classic many-to-many solution:

- `entries`: id (int), title (varchar[255]), content (text)
- `tags`: id (int), name (varchar[255]), slug (varchar[255])
- `entries_tags`: id (int), entry_id (int), tag_id (int)

Nothing out of ordinary so far. Now let's say I have test data in tags (I'm keeping out slugs as they are not important):

```
ID | name
1. | one 
2. | two 
3. | three
4. | four
5. | five
```

I also have three entries:

```
ID | title
1. | Something
2. | Blah blah blah
3. | Yay!
```

And relations:

```
ID | entry_id | tag_id
1. | 1        | 1
2. | 1        | 2
3. | 2        | 1
4. | 2        | 3
5. | 3        | 1
6. | 3        | 2
7. | 3        | 3
8. | 4        | 1
9. | 4        | 4
```

OK, we have our test data. I want to know how to get all entries that have tag One, but doesn't have tag Three (that'd be entries 1 and 4).

I know how to do it with subquery, the problem is, it takes a lot of time (with 100k entries it took about 10-15 seconds). Is there any way to do it with JOINs? Or am I missing something?

**edit** I guess I should've mentioned I need a solution that works with sets of data rather than single tags, so replace 'One' in my question with 'One', 'Two' and 'Two' with 'Three','Four'

**edit2** The answer provided is right, but it's too slow to be used practically. I guess the only way of making it work is using a 3rd-party search engine like Lucene or ElasticSearch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following script selects entries that have tags `One` and `Two` and do not have tags `Three` and `Four`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  et.entry_id
FROM entries_tags et
  INNER JOIN tags t1 ON et.tag_id = t1.id AND t1.name IN ('One', 'Two')
  LEFT JOIN  tags t2 ON et.tag_id = t2.id AND t2.name IN ('Three', 'Four')
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

---

Alternative solution: the `INNER JOIN` is replaced with `WHERE EXISTS`, which allows us to get rid from the (rather expensive) `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT
  et.entry_id
FROM entries_tags et
  LEFT JOIN  tags t2 ON et.tag_id = t2.id AND t2.name IN ('Three', 'Four')
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
  AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tags t1
    WHERE t1.id = et.tag_id
      AND t1.name IN ('One', 'Two')
  )
```

Comment: That did it in 1/3rd of the previous time (~5 seconds) and I guess that's the most you can get without caching the result and doing some kind of magic voodoo tricks. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Always welcome! Actually, there's another idea, and I've already updated my answer with its implementation. Would you please give it a try?

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want.

(It may or may not be faster than the sub query solution, I suggest you compare the query plans)

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.* 
FROM tags t1 
INNER JOIN entries_tags et1 ON t1.id=et1.tag_id 
INNER JOIN entries e ON e.entry_id=et1.entry_id 
INNER JOIN tags t2 on t2.name='three'
INNER JOIN tags t3 on t3.name='four'
LEFT JOIN entries_tags et2 ON (et1.entryid=et2.entryid AND t2.id = et2.tag_id ) 
       OR (et1.entryid=et2.entryid AND t3.id = et2.tag_id )
WHERE t1.name IN ('one','two') AND et2.name is NULL
```

By LEFT Joining the entries_tags table et2 (the data you do not want), you can then only select the records where the et2.name IS NULL (where the et2 record does not exist).

Comment: I'm not sure what you tried to do here but this query is completely broken. Or maybe I'm fixing it wrong (your table and field naming seems a little bit random)

Comment: I have modified my question a little bit, keep that in mind :)

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT e.* FROM tags t1 INNER JOIN entries_tags et1 ON t1.id=et1.tag_id INNER JOIN entries e ON e.id=et1.entry_id INNER JOIN tags t2 on t2.id=3 INNER JOIN tags t3 on t3.name=4 LEFT JOIN entries_tags et2 ON (et1.entry_id=et2.entry_id AND t2.id = et2.tag_id ) OR (et1.entry_id=et2.entry_id AND t3.id = et2.tag_id ) WHERE t1.id IN (1,2) AND et2.id is NULL;` - am I doing it wrong? still doesn't work (0 results)

Comment: apologies I do not have mysql here at the moment. INNER JOIN tags t3 on t3.name=4 looks a little suspect to me

Comment: Oh, you're right. Too bad it takes ~13 seconds anyway. I guess there's just no way of doing stuff like this efficiently...

Comment: I have no idea how the data is indexed, and where the query is spending most of the time... what happens if you put a compound index on entries_tags.entry_id and entries_tags.tag_id ?

Comment: I already have one. I guess it's because there're 1 mln of queries. Or maybe because MySQL and IN doesn't like eachother much. What I don't understand is why CLI MySQL shows 13 seconds query execution time while phpMyAdmin says it took less than a second (my bet is on some weird caching voodoo) In any case, looks like I'll have to re-think my approach and use Lucene or something similar.

Comment: perhaps analyzing the table will help ? see:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html

Comment: Didn't help much ;) Your answer is correct though, only impractical for me :)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned trying a subquery. Is this what you tried?

```
SELECT entries.id, entries.content
FROM entries
  LEFT JOIN entries_tags ON entries.id=entries_tags.entries_id
  LEFT JOIN tags ON entries_tags.tag_id=tags.id
WHERE tag.id=XX
  and entries.id NOT IN (
    SELECT entries.id
    FROM entries
      LEFT JOIN entries_tags ON entries.id=entries_tags.entries_id
      LEFT JOIN tags ON entries_tags.tag_id=tags.id
    WHERE tag.id=YY
  )
```

(Where XX is the tag you do want and YY is the tag you do not want)

With indices on the ID fields, that shouldn't be as slow as you say it is. It will depend on the data set, but it should be fine with indices (and with string comparisons omitted).

Comment: After changes (was broken in few places): `SELECT count(entries.id) FROM entries LEFT JOIN entries_tags ON entries.id=entries_tags.entry_id LEFT JOIN tags ON entries_tags.tag_id=tags.id WHERE tags.id IN (1,2) and entries.id NOT IN (SELECT entries.id FROM entries LEFT JOIN entries_tags ON entries.id=entries_tags.entry_id LEFT JOIN tags ON entries_tags.tag_id=tags.id WHERE tags.id IN (3,4));`. Took 13 seconds on my test database.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the IDs? You can check with SHOW CREATE TABLE [Table]. Also, how many items have tags 3 or 4?

Comment: [Table structure dump](http://pastebin.com/B9L680wb) . And we're talking about 1 mln entries and 1.172 mln entries_tags relations.